# Need generic xpath/css_selectro for following html code

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

Following is the html code for which I need generic xpath pr css_selector

```
<fieldset>
<legend>Forged Email:</legend>
<p class="custom-err-pos-handle">
<input id="domainforging" class="required custom-err-pos valid"  name="forgedemailoption" value="f" aria-required="true" type="checkbox">
<label for="domainforging" style="width:auto" title="Checks that the envelope from domain matches the emails from domain">Envelope Domain Forging</label>
<br>
<input id="replytoheader" class="required custom-err-pos" name="forgedemailoption" value="r" type="checkbox">
<label for="replytoheader" style="width:auto" title="Checks that the domain of the reply-to address matches the envelope from domain">Reply-to Domain Forging</label>
<br>
<input id="headerdomain" class="required custom-err-pos" name="forgedemailoption" value="h" type="checkbox">
<label for="headerdomain" style="width:auto" title="Checks to see if the email From domain has been forged">Header Domain Forging</label>
</p>
</fieldset>
```

Need to pass values "Envelope Domain Forging" or "Reply-to Domain Forging" or "Header Domain Forging".

Comment: `I need generic xpath pr css_selector` for what?? label or input??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using JAVA then,create a String type locator like following:-

private String locatorName = //label[text()='%s'];

use the above like this

public void passValueMethod(String value){

WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(String.format(locatorName,value)));

}

everytime you call the method passValueMethod with different argument,it will be passed to the locator dynamically.

Comment: Thanks Shubham, it works.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use text nodes to identify element, then you might need this `XPath`:

```
text = "Envelope Domain Forging"
'//input/label[text()="%s"]' % text
```

Comment: This does not work :(